# What is precisely a "Side Effect" in redux other than async operations?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In redux docs [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts),

`They must not do any asynchronous logic, calculate random values, or cause other "side effects"`

I just don't understand why have they used "other" side effects. I mean what defines a "side effect" to be precise?

Comment: It probably means, any sort of impure action (such as mutating/reassigning an outside variable, or changing the DOM) should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer is intended to be a pure function. Functional purity is built around the idea the function only deals with inputs (params) and outputs (return statements). It doesn't affect anything outside of the function body. If it does, that's considered a *[side-effect](https://g.co/kgs/jHKb94)*.

Consider a closure in JavaScript.

```
function outer(a, b) {
    let x = 1
    
    function inner(c, d) {
        // x is not a param (input) and it's not declared in `inner`
        // which means it's changing state not local to the itself, thus
        // a side-effect
        x = 3

        return a + b
    }
}
```

If I call `inner`, it effects state *outside of the function* by setting x, which is declared in `outer.`

Another side-effect in the context of react would be to set a value directly in the DOM, e.g., `document.title = "Hi, mom!"` The DOM api affects models outside the scope of your function, so that's a side-effect.

Comment: That clarifies it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Side effect is a programming term to define changes in kind of state, in redux context this mean some changes in states beyond our reducer scope has.

Example:

```js
//counter.js

export default {
 numberOfItems: 0;
};
```

```js
import counter from '../counter'

function exampleReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'PUSH_VALUE':
     
      // For redux this operation below is considered a side effect because change a kind of state beyond its scope.
      counter.numberOfItems = state.length + 1;

      return [...state, action.payload];

    case 'POP_VALUE':

      // This is another side effect. 
      counter.numberOfItems = state.length - 1;

      return [...state.pop()];
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```